# Is there a CallingMemberName-Attribute?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I know the CallerMemberName-attribute, which replaces the null parameter with, for example, the property name you are calling the method from.

This is very useful for things like PropertyChanged-Notifications. Currently we have a different scenario, where we would like to have a parameter-attribute which replaces the null parameter with the method name you're calling.

Generally speaking, is it possible to do something like this?
To be honest, I havent dealt much with custom attribute yet, but in our case, it would be kinda interesting to have something like this.
Is there any helpful Information I can start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such attribute, but you could use C# 6 `nameof` operator:

```
public void SomeMethod ()
{
    Console.WriteLine(nameof(SomeMethod));
}
```

Of course this does not dynamically and automatically inserts the name of the method you are in, but requires you to have an actual reference to the method. However, it supports full IntelliSense and will also update automatically when you refactor the method name. And the name is inserted at compile time, so you don’t get any performance downside.

If you wanted to place this code in a more central place, like you do with e.g. INPC implementations in base view models, then your idea is a bit flawed anyway. If you had a common method you call to figure out the method name you’re in, then it would always report the method name of the common method:

```
public void SomeMethod ()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetMethodName());
}

// assuming that a CallingMemberNameAttribute existed
public string GetMethodName([CallingMemberName] string callingMember = null)
{
    return callingMember; // would be always "GetMethodName"
}
```

But instead, you could use the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` here again, which will then correctly get the method name calling the `GetMethodName` function:

```
public void SomeMethod ()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetMethodName());
}

public string GetMethodName([CallerMemberNamed] string callerMember = null)
{
    return callerMember;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that´s a nice idea at the end :)